# How to access an element in react native which is loaded when a certain state of the component is true?

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I am using jest for unit testing in React native. A part of my UI inside a component is loaded only when a particular state of the component (noRecord) is true.
Here is the code snippet:

```
{this.state.noRecord ? 
<View>
<TouchableOpacity id="navEnqtrn" onPress={() => this.navEnqtrn()}>
<Text style={styles.courseEnquiry}> Learning enquiry </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
<View> : <View> <Text>Some other view here..</Text></View>
}
```

Here is my unit test case:

```
it('checks navEnqtrn' , () => {
const wrapper = shallow(<Online navigation = {navigation}/>);
wrapper.state.noRecord = true;
const instance = wrapper.instance();
const navEnqtrnSpy = jest.spyOn(instance,"navEnqtrn");
wrapper.find('#navEnqtrn').simulate('press');
expect(navEnqtrnSpy).toBeCalled();
});
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Method “simulate” is only meant to be run on a single node. 0 found instead.

  at ShallowWrapper.single (node_modules/enzyme/build/ShallowWrapper.js:1618:17)
  at ShallowWrapper.simulate (node_modules/enzyme/build/ShallowWrapper.js:929:21)
  at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/online-test.js:100:28)
  at tryCallTwo (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:45:5)
  at doResolve (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:200:13)
  at new Promise (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:66:3)
  at tryCallOne (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)
  at node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:123:15
  at flush (node_modules/asap/raw.js:50:29)
  at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

How do I simulate the press event in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Try and add to the shallow wrapper the `.dive()` functionality. When you are messing with the state is not the correct div rather than the HOC

Like this

```
const wrapper = shallow(<Online navigation = {navigation}/>).dive();
```